# TextBox and On Screen Keyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, on-screen-keyboard

Is there any way to show something on top of WindowsPhone 8 On Screen Keyboard, such as a Grid, PopUp or StackPanel so I can cover it.

Comment: Is there a reason `IsReadOnly` didn't work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954103/hide-on-screen-keyboard-without-using-focus-on-another-element As for this question, there's no way to put something on top of the keyboard.

Comment: It's working but that method cannot used in my application because I want to select text directly from the TextBox by using my fingers. Thank you any way I have been struggling with this issue more than a month now. It seems like there is no option rather than using TextBlocks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test it at the moment but I think setting it as readonly should allow you to select and copy the text. Might need to double tap on it.

Comment: Yes I think you very much this may solve lots of my problems

Comment: But the textbox is not automatically scroll down when I'm writing on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you wan't put something above the `On Screen Keyboard` in WindowsPhone, the On Screen Keyboard is a system object, you don't have direct access to it, nor you can put something above it it has Visually more priority than your applications Elements